# Python type hinting: how to tell X is a subclass for Foo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, type-hinting

How should I write a type hint for class types in Python?
Consider this code:

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def register(cls: type[A]):
    assert issubclass(cls, A)

 register(A)
 register(B)
```

Is `type[A]` the correct way to write this?
If I'd just use `cls: A` it would mean `cls` is an instance of `A`, but I want to to say `cls` is a class/type, which at least subclasses `A`.

Specifically, what I want to indicate is that the parameter should be 
a Django model type.

Comment: If you will search for typehint (doc string hint) in PyCharm i upset you: currently you could not  use typehints for class subtypes in PyCharm.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092104/subclass-in-type-hinting/65649424#65649424) discuss the subject. It may help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It seems like other current (22 Sep 2016) answers here are incorrect. According to PEP 484 (about Type Hints), there exists a hint for type of class objects, called [Type[C]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects). And according to `typing` module's documentation, you can use [typing.Type[C]](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.Type) to achieve exactly what you want. I'm using those myself with Python 3.5.2.

Quoting [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects):

> Sometimes you want to talk about class objects, in particular class objects that inherit from a given class. This can be spelled as Type[C] where C is a class. To clarify: while C (when used as an annotation) refers to instances of class C , Type[C] refers to subclasses of C .

And quoting [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

> A variable annotated with C may accept a value of type C. In contrast, a variable annotated with Type[C] may accept values that are classes themselves – specifically, it will accept the class object of C.

And referring to your specific example:

```
import typing

class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def register(cls: typing.Type[A]):
    assert issubclass(cls, A)

register(A)
register(B)
```

You can check such code statically using [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy), and it should work in simple cases -- beware however that mypy is a work in progress, as of now there are several issues open about Type[C] hinting.

Comment: What about multiple inheritance, is it possible to annotate cls must belong to two types?

Comment: @laike9m As of today, no: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213 - but it might land in Python one day.

Answer (score 3):

To solve your general case, you would have to write a metaclass with a suitable `__subclasscheck__`. Possible, but cumbersome.

In your specific case of Django model classes, an explicit metaclass already exists, so annotating that should do the job:

```
import django.db.model as model

def register(cls: model.base.ModelBase): ...
```

This will work because `isinstance(models.Model, models.base.ModelBase)` is true.