# Python: how to override type hint on an instance attribute in a subclass?

Tags: python, pycharm, subclass, type-hinting, typing

Before you dive in, here is my question: how can I use type hints in a subclass to specify a different type on an instance attribute?

If you are unclear on what that means, read below, where I have drawn up an example to clarify things.

---

**Full Explanation**

I have an abstract class `Foo`, and a subclass of `Foo` called `SubclassOfFoo`.

`Foo` has an abstract method `get_something` that returns an object of type `Something`.

`Something` has a subclass called `SubclassOfSomething`.  `SubclassOfSomething` has an additional method `something_special`.

`SubclassOfFoo` overrides `get_something` to return an object of type `SubclassOfSomething`.  Then, `SubclassOfFoo` tries to use `SubclassOfSomething`'s method `something_special`.

However, currently my PyCharm's inspections are reporting `Unresolved attribute reference 'something_special' for class 'Something'`.  I am trying to figure out the correct way to fix this.

This is all very confusing, so I have made a nice little code snippet to help here:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 0


class SubclassOfSomething(Something):
    def __init__(self):
        Something.__init__(self)

    def something_special(self):
        self.attr = 1


class Foo(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_class = self.get_something()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_something(self) -> Something:
        pass


class SubclassOfFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self)

    def get_something(self) -> SubclassOfSomething:
        return SubclassOfSomething()

    def do_something_special(self):
        self.my_class.something_special()
```

Basically, in order to get everything to work out, I can do one of several things:

1. Remove the type hint on the return of `get_something` within `Foo`
2. Use a type hint in `SubclassOfFoo` for `self.my_class` to clear things up
3. Use generics?

Option 1. is what I am trying to avoid

Option 2. is not bad, but I can't figure it out

Option 3. is also an option.

I am also open to other options, as I am sure there is a better way.

**Can you please help me figure out the correct way to handle this?**

---

**What I Have Tried**

To emulate option 2., I tried using `typing.Type` as suggested here: [Subclass in type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092104/subclass-in-type-hinting)

However, this was not working for me.

Comment: @101arrowz: That type hint is there because the more specific return type information is important. An arbitrary instance of `Something` cannot be assumed to have a `something_special` method.

Comment: I suspect the best option will be to make `Foo` generic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give a type hint on `my_class` attribute in the beginning of class definition:

```
class SubclassOfFoo(Foo):
    my_class: SubclassOfSomething  # <- here

    def get_something(self) -> SubclassOfSomething:
        return SubclassOfSomething()

    def do_something_special(self):
        self.my_class.something_special()
```

After that there is no warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'something_special' for class 'Something'` from PyCharm inspection because now `my_class` is known to be `SubclassOfSomething` not `Something`.

Comment: That does solve the problem @sanyash.  I am curious, what is that general method called?

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand why it works.  `my_class` is an instance attribute within `SubclassOfFoo`.  Putting the type hint `my_class: SubclassOfSomething ` inside of `__init__` does not fix the problem.  It only fixes the problem when put into the class scope of `SubclassOfFoo`.  Why is that?  Shouldn't `self.my_class` be scoped to the instance, and not affected by a type hint within a class scope?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer please check this PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations. It is stated that variables described as `my_class: SubclassOfSomething` in class scope are treated as instance attributes while `my_class: ClassVar[SubclassOfSomething]` is treated like class variable, not an instance attribbute.

Comment: Okay that clears me up, thank you again @sanyash!  This is a nice functionality

Answer (score 13):

Using generics:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


SomethingT = TypeVar('SomethingT', bound='Something')


...


class Foo(ABC, Generic[SomethingT]):
    my_class: SomethingT

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_class = self.get_something()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_something(self) -> SomethingT:
        pass


class SubclassOfFoo(Foo[SubclassOfSomething]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_something(self) -> SubclassOfSomething:
        return SubclassOfSomething()

    def do_something_special(self):
        # inferred type of `self.my_class` will be `SubclassOfSomething`
        self.my_class.something_special()
```

Comment: Thank you @user2235698 for hashing out the syntax!  That works correctly in PyCharm on my end.  I will keep this for future reference

Answer (score 2):

You could provide the `something_special` method on `Something` too, and raise a `NotImplementedError`

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 0

    def something_special(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

This resolves your type hinting issue, although functionally it will raise an exception at the same point (if you managed to get a `Something` somehow and try to call `something_special`, just will be `NotImplementedError` instead of `AttributeError`).

Maybe in some situations you might want to just `pass` instead, depending on what `something_special` actually is.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 0

    def validate(self):
        # doesn't want to perform validation
        pass


class SubclassOfSomething(Something):
    def __init__(self):
        Something.__init__(self)

    def validate(self):
        if self.attr < 0:
            raise ValueError()
```

The important underlying thing is making sure your class hierarchy conforms to a common interface - public methods on subclasses but not on parents goes against that and reduces the polymorphism of objects in your class hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RachSharp!  Yes both of those also are valid, upvoted!

Comment: Unfortunately, in my actual use case (not the idealized code I have placed here), `Something` and `SubclassOfSomething` are both inside a 3rd party package, and I would prefer to have the type hinting taken care of within my own code