# type hint from a class property

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a use case where I would like to define a common function in a base class, but annotate the return type from an overridden property in a subclass. This is a silly example, but clearly demonstrates what I would like to do:

```py
from typing import Any

class BaseCls:
    RETURNS_TYPE: Any = NotImplemented

    # This is what I am not sure how to do, this does not work
    # Have tried a few different things, but hoping someone just knows
    def cast_to_return_type(self: 'BaseCls', value: Any) -> 'BaseCls.RETURNS_TYPE':
        return some_work_that_returns_self_RETURNS_TYPE()

class IntCls(BaseCls):
    RETURNS_TYPE = int

class StrCls(BaseCls):
    RETURNS_TYPE = str
```

How can I type hint the return value of `cast_to_return_type` so that a a regular old IDE would be able to detect what the return type should be when doing `StrCls().cast_to_return_type(some_var)` (tried on pycharm and vscode, neither knew what to do any decided `Any` was the return type, which makes sense if it cant infer the child class value)

Comment: This might help you, have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146406/python-overriding-type-hint-on-a-methods-return-in-child-class-without-redefin

Comment: What do you mean by "a regular old IDE"?

Comment: I think this goes against the LSP, use generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing that `typing` has to type variables is `typing.TypeVar`.  Their use is to create a generic class, in the same way that you write `list[int]` or `Mapping[str, str]`.

So we can rewrite your code so that `BaseCls` is a generic type, with a type variable `ReturnsType`.  (You should only use all caps for constants.)

The subclasses `IntCls` and `StrCls` "assign" to the type variable by including the type inside square braces after the type they are subclassing.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any

ReturnsType = TypeVar('ReturnsType')

class BaseCls(Generic[ReturnsType]):
    def cast_to_return_type(self, value: Any) -> ReturnsType:
        return some_work_that_returns_self_RETURNS_TYPE()

class IntCls(BaseCls[int]):
    pass

class StrCls(BaseCls[str]):
    pass
```