# python/pycharm type hinting with base class?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

the base class here is actually an abstract class provides basic methods with type hints, and the subclasses overwrite them with the same parameters.

i tried the below code, wanted to let values in dictionary `mp` hint these basic methods but it doesn't work.

```py
from typing import Dict

class Base:
    pass

class A(Base):
    pass

class B(Base):
    pass


mp: Dict[str, Base] = {
    "A": A,
    "B": B
}
```

the Pycharm IDE warned *Expected type 'Dict[str, Base]', got 'Dict[str, Union[A, B]]' instead*.

i wonder what the correct way is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092104/subclass-in-type-hinting

Comment: thank you @MaxNoe it worked. i should try searching sub class instead of base class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as the above friend @MaxNoe mentioned, i should use the code below

```py
from typing import Dict, Type

class Base:
    pass

class A(Base):
    pass

class B(Base):
    pass


mp: Dict[str, Type[Base]] = {
    "A": A,
    "B": B
}
```