# python type hinting for pydantic schema/model

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm trying to specify a type hinting for every function in my code.
How I can specify the type hinting for a function which waiting for any pydantic schema (model)?

Here is my code:

```
def hash_password(password: str, schema = None) -> str:
    if schema:
        del schema.password if hasattr(schema, 'password') else None
    return config.pwd_context.hash(password)
```

Example model:

```
my_schema = schemas.UserBase(full_name='a b c')  # just a text
type(my_schema)  # <class 'app.schemas.UserBase'>
```

Comment: Is it not just `pydantic.BaseModel`?

Comment: @Kemp no, if you using some intermediate class as `BaceSchemaName` (which inherits from a `BaseModel`)

Comment: Ah, my mistake, it's `Type[pydantic.BaseModel]` to allow derived classes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46092347/3228591).

Answer (score 0):

You could import your schema from the module: *from app.schemas import UserBase*. And then type hint this object to your function:

```
def your_function() -> UserBase:
    ...
```

If I understood correctly, this is what you wanted to do.
If it does not fit on your needs, let me know!