# How do I use type hint for multiple classes in a dictionary but they inherit from same parent class?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to use type hint with string as a key and different classes as a value in a dictionary like below.

```
configurations: Dict[str, what_class??] = {
    "dev": Dev,
    "product": Product,
    "test": Test,
}
```

The classes Dev, Product, Test inherit from a base class "Parent".

```
class Parent:
    pass

class Dev(Parent):
    pass

class Product(Parent):
    pass

class Test(Parent):
    pass
```

What is the best way to do the type hint for this?

Do I need to set just "Any" as their type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subclass in type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092104/subclass-in-type-hinting)

Comment: @MariusROBERT the answer you linked gave me a hint to think about this situation but the most accurate answer was the one from Ron Serruya. It was good to read the answer to get a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how accurate you want your hints to be,

1. Use the parent class

```py
configurations: Dict[str, Parent] = {
    "dev": Dev,
    "product": Product,
    "test": Test,
}
```

2. Specify the classes in a union

```py
from typing import Union
configurations: Dict[str, Union[Dev, Product, Test]] = {
    "dev": Dev,
    "product": Product,
    "test": Test,
}
```

3. Create a TypedDict type for this specific dict

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class EnvDict(TypedDict):
    dev: Dev
    product: Product
    test: Test
    
configurations: EnvDict = {
    "dev": Dev,
    "product": Product,
    "test": Test,
}
```

Comment: Seems like the third one was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, creating a dictionary without using type hints seems the most optimal solution, as you can access all classes directly from the dict variable *configurations*, using the proper string key value:

```
class Parent:
    pass

class Dev(Parent):
    pass

class Product(Parent):
    pass

class Test(Parent):
    pass

configurations = {
    "dev": Dev,
    "product": Product,
    "test": Test,
}

print(configurations)
```

**Output:**

```
{'dev': <class '__main__.Dev'>, 'product': <class '__main__.Product'>, 'test': <class '__main__.Test'>}
```

Also, using the `Parent` class works well if you still want to use type hints:

```
import typing
class Parent:
    pass

class Dev(Parent):
    pass

class Product(Parent):
    pass

class Test(Parent):
    pass

configurations: typing.Dict[str, Parent] = {
    "dev": Dev,
    "product": Product,
    "test": Test,
}
print(configurations)
```

It outputs the same dictionary as the above code.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using type hints seems the most optimal solution"? is your view to type hinting is optional?

Comment: @eric-lee I just proposed it as another solution, which I consider the best. However, I don't know the full project that is behind that solution.

Comment: I see. I just wanted to implement type hinting for my code looking better for others. Thanks for the advices.