# Type hint for returning non-instantiated class type

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, type-hinting

I have a situation where I want to return a non instantiated class object, a type. I would go for `->type`, as non-instantiated classes are of type 'type', but the function is not supposed to return 'any class type', I'm interested only in returning one of class types that inherits from A, because on instantiated object of this class I'm later to run some methods specific for it.

To better illustrate this, here is a sample code. The question is this possible to put some reasoned type annotation in this case? or if not what would be the correct practice in such situation?

```
class A():
    def run(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

def get_letter_class(condition: str) -> ?:
    if condition == 'b':
        return B
    elif condition == 'c':
        return C

class_type = get_letter_class('b')
letter = class_type()
letter.run()
```

Comment: I think this should be reopened.  The answer can be found in the answers to the other question but it is not really a duplicate.  The question here makes it very clear that a non-instantiated type is returned while the other question is unclear but I think an instance is meant.

Answer (score 5):

If your function supposed to return classes instead of their instances then we can use

#### Python3.9+

`type` as generic

```py
from typing import Type
...
def get_letter_class(condition: str) -> type[A]:
```

#### before Python3.9

[`typing.Type` generic](https://docs.python.org/library/typing.html#typing.Type)

```py
from typing import Type
...
def get_letter_class(condition: str) -> Type[A]:
```

## Further reading

- [PEP-484 entry](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects).
- [PEP-585 entry](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#implementation)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I previously read in another subject [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205960/python-type-hinting-how-to-tell-x-is-a-subclass-for-foo) the `Type[A]` can indicate also an instantiated object of type inheriting from A. I'm reading it second time now. Pleas correct me if I'm wrong here, because now after your answer and reading above link I understand it like this: `Type[A]` can mean both.an instantiated object of type inheriting from `A` and a non-instantiated class object itself? is this correct? a bit not logical for me why would they do it like that TBH

Comment: @tikej: `Type[A]` means any class object which is a subclass of `A` (including `A` itself), not an instance, but class

Comment: @tikej: The answers in your link don't make any claim that `Type[A]` accepts instances.

Comment: thanks for the answers. just a side question then, what to use if I want to hint returning of an instantiated object of type inheriting from another class?

Comment: @tikej: can you provide a code example (because I don't understand)? also you can ask another question and mention it here in the comments