# How do I add type annotations for same-type arguments generically?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Let's say I have a function that is able to compare fruits, I could explicitly mention this in type annotations like this:

```py
def compare_fruits(one: Fruit, other: Fruit) -> bool:
    assert type(one) is type(other)  #  <-- type hint for this
    ...
```

This implies it would be a valid operation to compare an `Apple` and `Pear` objects as subclasses, **but it's not for my program**. I'd like to find a way to type-annotate the function's arguments with an generic of "same-type". I think I know how to do that in [abstract classes with user-defined Generic types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types), but it's not clear to me how to do this for plain functions.

I tried this the naive way:

```py
FruitType = TypeVar("FruitType")


def compare_fruits(one: Generic[FruitType], other: Generic[FruitType]) -> bool:
    ...
```

yields `error: Variable "typing.Generic" is not valid as a type` in mypy, which makes sense.

Then I tried this:

```py
FruitType = TypeVar("FruitType")


class MyFruitModule(Generic[FruitType]):

    @staticmethod
    def compare(one: FruitType, other: FruitType) -> bool:
        ...


compare_apples = MyFruitModule[Apple].compare  # still not implicit same-type
```

Any ideas or a source about that this is simply impossible as of the moment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hinting: how to tell X is a subclass for Foo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205960/python-type-hinting-how-to-tell-x-is-a-subclass-for-foo)

Comment: Why do you keep using `Generic`, that isn't what it is for

Comment: You just mean something like `FruitType = TypeVar("FruitType", bound=Fruit)`? Then annotate it with `FruitType` Note, if you mean *any* type, then `FruitType = TypeVar("FruitType")` would already do that. You would just have to annotate it with `def compare_fruits(one: FruitType, other: FruitType) -> bool:` which to me seems to be the naive way (again, not sure why you are involving `Generic` at all)

Comment: No I don't want any subclass to match. Like I explained, comparing an Apple and a Pear does not make sense in my use case. I'd like to type-hint same-type arguments, ie. `assert type(one) is type(other)`-safe.

Comment: In principle, a regular function with invariant TypeVar like ``compare(a: FruitType, b: FruitType)`` should do... but [mypy seems not to enforce that](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=d11875a01588d249985a6807ade250bd&flags=strict) and even happily accept variance for in/out types.